# Meaning and English translation of adjective "link"

Tags: translation

I'm having trouble finding an appropriate English translation for the adjective "link" used in the examples below:

> "Der **linke** Begriff des Establishments wird ihm zur Waffe."
>
> "... einen weißen Mob gegen einen bestimmt nicht **linken** Politikbetrieb mobilisieren kann, ..."

I have "misleading" for the first one, but can't quite figure out a suitable word for the second. If I am on the right track, that is? I hadn't come across this word before until now.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The ‘base form’ is *links.* [See Wiktionary (although it lists it as *linker)*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/linker#German)

Comment: Maybe your question and its answer would have been useful to someone else.

Comment: FWIW, my close vote was for General References.

Answer (score 2):

In both sentences you would say "leftist" in English. In the second one you could also say "left-wing".

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different meanings for this word. Your examples seem to have a political context.

*Links* means Left in this context and stands for a politcal "direction". Like left or right politicians.

Answer (score 0):

If the word in your examples mean the political orientation [*Links*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politische_Linke), [*left-wing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-wing_politics) as suggested by [@fdb](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/34975/meaning-and-english-translation-of-adjective-link/34977#34977) is the correct translation.

But *linke/linken* could also have a different meaning:
The adjective [*link*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/link) means [*deceitful*/*dubious*](https://www.dict.cc/?s=link).

In my experience *link* not very common nowadays, but you can't rule it out completely. And in my opinion there is not enough context in your examples to know which meaning is intended here.